# What Is the most popular combination of technologies used to building Reactjs web apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend

I'm mid PHP/Laravel developer with some exp in jQuery and Vue.js
I want to start self-learning in reactive JS frameworks (for example ReactJS), because I see is the near future in web development.

I checked the [React + redux] is the most popular technology working on browser side, but what about back-end ? 
Secured API to PHP/MySQL? or maybe run apps directly on NodeJS server ? if nodejs env. then where will be storing the data ? SQL? NoSQL?

Tell me please what back-end stack is the most popular? or what stack is the near future ?

What about PWA with ReactJS ?

Thank You!

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. I would say maybe GO or Java. Node.js is also a good choice.

Comment: There are a large number of configurations and languages for back end technologies.  It could be Java, it could be Python, it could be Node.js, it could be C#..do you see where I'm going with this?  As the previous comment said, it's dependent on your requirements, but it's also dependent on the company you are working for.  Company A may be strictly a Java shop and Company B might be a strictly Python shop.  I would pick one and learn it.  There's no right answer.

Comment: ReactJs + Redux + fire base or ReactJs + Redux + REST + Spring-boot  different type of purpose

Answer (score 0):

In my experience node.js is more popular for startups and makes it easy to work with since its all javascript.

Java and C# tend to be popular in large enterprise companies

SQL systems, such as MYSQL and PSQL are by and far the most popular options for both small and large companies.

SQL systems such as, Oracle and Microsoft SQL server, are the most popular in extremely large companies.

MongoDB is the most popular NoSQL db but its not used as often in production.

PHP as a server side language is used in about 80% of websites, but that is mostly because of wordpress, I have personally never seen a React frontend being implemented with a PHP backend.

Django and flask are popular python server frameworks but I find them to be popular with AngularJS( the original angular not angular 2+) not React.

The most common stack Ive seen is React, Redux, Express, PSQL, AWS.

https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all

https://db-engines.com/en/ranking

Answer (score 0):

Hi with my previous experience

**ReactJs + Redux + fire base**
this is very good technical combination you can use 
reactJs , redux , meterilaUI,Sementic UI,ant design for front end. 
and fire base can easily connected with your application.
**advantage of this architecture the app will real time data application , no end point integration , quickly development , easy to authenticate**

[sample project](https://github.com/YasanthaHennayake/react-redux-firebase-boilerplate)

**ReactJs + Redux + REST + Spring-boot** in this project back end service developed using java spring-boot and it possible for connect any relational data bases such as Oracle , MYSql, NoSql , even any kind of Data bases using **Spting-Data-JPA** or **Hibernate** , **JPA**.

But authentication and state management not much easy. need to implement **JWT** to any  state management method because REST is stateless. 
**advantage is good for micro services architecture , easy to build react app inside spring boot (packaging as .jar .war) and deployee j2EE server.**

[sample project](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/)

i have already developed project based on these 2 technologies stacks both are worked as my different requirements.